# Replace the param in url using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, url

I would like to know how to replace the param in the url using javascript without regex.
for example,
I need to change param value `amt=100` to `amt=2000` of url using javascript.

```
url1 ="www.xyz.com?src=service&amt=100&day=10"
url2="www.xyz.com?src=service&amt=200&day=10"

function changeUrl(url, newamt){
   var newurl= location.split("=")[1].replace(newamt);
   return newurl
}

changeUrl(url1, 2000);
changeUrl(url2, 1500);
Expected Output:
www.xyz.com?src=service&amt=2000&day=10
www.xyz.com?src=service&amt=1500&day=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function to do so.

```js
function changeUrl(url, newamt){
   var href = new URL(url);
   href.searchParams.set('amt', newamt);
   return href.toString();
}

console.log(changeUrl("https://www.example.com?src=service&amt=100&day=10", 2000));
console.log(changeUrl("https://www.example.com?src=service&amt=200&day=10", 1500));
```